# how to see PHP response when calling from console?

Tags: php, c, yii, httpresponse

I have a `C` program that calls a `PHP` `script`. My question is how do I get the script's response parameters such as `status code`(to know if everything ended ok) or `body`?
Of course I need to do different things on different responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use popen function to get return value from PHP script for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE *in;
    extern FILE *popen();
    char buff[512];
    if(!(in = popen("your commad", "r"))){

        exit(1);

    }
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){

        printf("%s", buff);

    }
    pclose(in);
}
```

You will have return value in `buff` variable after executing command in `popen`